# NoMethodError when using ruby refinements

Tags: ruby

I'm using ruby's refinements to monkey-patch a method into the Math class like so:

```
module Radians
  refine Math do
    def radians(degrees)
      degrees * Math::PI / 180
    end
  end
end
```

I then try to call my monkey-patched method in a class like so:

```
class Foo
  using Radians
  def bar
    Math.radians(180)
  end
end

Foo.new.bar
```

This throws an `` undefined method `radians' for Math:Module (NoMethodError) ``

What am I doing wrong? My ruby version is `2.5.1p57`. I've consulted the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) and I think what I've done is correct, but obviously not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're defining an instance method, but calling a singleton method.

You need to refine the Math module's singleton class instead:

```
module Radians
  refine Math.singleton_class do
    def radians(degrees)
      degrees * Math::PI / 180
    end
  end
end
```